# periodic BLE disconnects with iOS11

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ios11

We have a BLE system in which our iPad mini App connects (using CBCentralManager) to a Nordic embedded BLE peripheral which we have also developed.  The peripheral detects pressure and sends it to the App at around 10hz.  This has all worked great for a couple of years.

We recently upgraded the iPad mini to iOS11, and we are seeing a strange thing: every minute or two it disconnects spontaneously.  We see this on iOS11, not iOS10 (all else equal).  While debugging I see that our handler is called:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
```

with NSError data seemingly code=0.  I'm kind of at my wit's end, not even sure how to troubleshoot... is there any tracing or call stack examination that can give me a clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Is this thing on?